# keeping the header fixed in datatable while allowing its contents to scroll

Tags: jsf

I have a table with header and data. When I am scrolling the header is also getting scrolled my code is as follows:

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <h:dataTable cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="60%"
        headerClass="HeaderCellSorted" columnClasses="DataCell" rowClasses="OddRow,EvenRow" styleClass="SearchResults" footerClass="FooterCell" 
        id="userListTable" value="#{pc_WorkInProgressUserGrid.userGridModel.rebalanceByUserList}" var="userGridDO">
        <h:column id="userNameColumn">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLink id="userNameColumnLink" styleClass="Header" value="#" onclick="refreshUserGrid('DISPLAYNAME')">
                    <h:outputText id="userNameColID" styleClass="outputText" value="User"/>
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is in fact an easy task with CSS:

```
tbody {
    height: 200px; /* Just some fixed height */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

But a certain widely used webbrowser developed by a team in Redmond doesn't support the `overflow` property on the `tbody` element. So you're really stuck and you'll need to head to hacky HTML+CSS and/or Javascript based solutions.

- Google:  "[scrollable table with fixed header](http://www.google.com/search?q=scrollable+table+with+fixed+header)"
- Stackoverflow: "[scrollable table with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrollable+table+with+fixed+header)"

There's by the way also a [jQuery plugin](http://fixedheadertable.mmalek.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use RichFaces, they offer the ExtendedDataTable which has the functionality you're looking for.  See http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf.